# how to share data between ViewPager fragments?

Tags: android

I just started with android programming, therefore my code looks pretty ugly. It is cobbled together from various tutorials and almost does what I need it to. A quick explanation what I need it to do:

I have an activity with two tabs. One tab implements an OnClickListener on the whole screen which increments a counter every time the screen is clicked. If the screen is swiped from top to bottom, or from bottom to top, that counter is reset to 0. Now, what I have been struggling with: When I swipe to the next tab, I want the current value of that counter to be passed to the next fragment where it shall be used for calculations.

Can anyone help me out here?

I will also happily accept any comments that help me clean up my current code.

Cheers

Here is my current code:

Main Activity's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <de.regenistdoof.sporecounter.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity:

```
package de.regenistdoof.sporecounter;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                MainActivity.this));



        // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager
        SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        // Center the tabs in the layout
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Counter Fragment's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This is the fragment  to be displayed for a section associated with a tab -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:text="@string/counter_default"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="50sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Counter Fragment code:

```
package de.regenistdoof.sporecounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

// In this case, the fragment displays simple text based on the page
public class FragmentCounter extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{

int count = 0;
TextView counter;
LinearLayout layout;
View view;
boolean swipe = false;
String TAG = "sporecounter";



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_counter, container, false);

        layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.setOnClickListener(this);

        counter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {


                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                                           float velocityY) {

                        final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 300;

                        try {
                            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && e1.getY() > e2.getY()){
                                Log.d(TAG, "swipe up");
                                count = 0;
                                swipe = true;
                                counter.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                            }
                            else if ((Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && e2.getY() > e1.getY())){
                                Log.d(TAG, "swipe down");
                                count = 0;
                                swipe = true;
                                counter.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // nothing
                        }
                        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                    }
                });

        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         if (swipe) {
             counter.setText("0");
             swipe = false;
         } else {
             count++;
             counter.setText(Integer.toString(count));
         }
     }


    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

These are the important bits that made the solution work for my code:

The idea was: FragmentCounter increases counter --> sets value in MainActivity --> MainActivity calls updateCall method in FragmentCalculations --> FragmentCalculations updates textview.

Main Activity:

```
private FragmentCalculations fragcalc;

    // get latest count from FragmentCounter and call updateCall method in FragmentCalculations
    public void setLastCount(int count) {
        ((FragmentCalculations)fragcalc).updateCall(count);
    }
```

FragmentCounter:
This code goes into the onclicklistener of the button which I use to increment my counter:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).setLastCount(count);
```

FragmentCalculations:

```
public class FragmentCalculations extends Fragment{

public static EditText numberOfSquaresRef, countedCellsRef;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculation, container, false);

    countedCellsRef = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.counted_cells);

 public void updateCall(int count){
    Log.d(TAG, "fragcalc value: " + count);
    countedCellsRef.setText(""+count);
}
```

Comment: This will be migrated to StackOverflow for you since it's programming related. Please read about each StackExchange site's scope before posting a question.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was logged in on StackOverflow but when playing around in my profile I ended up here. Can I move it myself, or shall I just close this and open a new question there?

Comment: Don't duplicate. I've voted to move it but if you want you can flag it and write a short note for the mods.

Comment: I flagged it, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Manage the counter from the activity, and register the fragments as listeners that are updated from the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the last value in the MainActivtiy.

Example:

In the MainActivity:

```
private int lastCount;

public int getLastCount() {
    return this.lastCount;
}

public void setLastCount(int newValue) {
    this.lastCount = newValue;
}
```

And in your fragment:

```
//Set the value:
((MainActivity) getActivity()).setLastCount(999);

//Get the value:
int lastCount = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getLastCount();
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this way I get my value over to the other fragment. Now the problem however is, I need to invoke some sort of action like a button click in that fragment to get the value from the mainActivity. I would love to have the value update itself as soon as I swipe to the fragment, or when I increment the counter in the other fragment.
I understand that might not be possible, since the viewpager populates both fragments when starting the app to make them swipeable.
Thanks

Comment: To explain a bit better what I want to do:

![image of my fragments](http://www.debler.net/fragments.png)

A click on fragment 1 increments the counter, then I want to swipe over to fragment 2. "newValue" should then automatically pull the latest counter value from the mainActivity, and a click on "Button" will then perform a calculation with this latest "newValue".

Comment: For this you can use an interface (more information about that you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) ) or you expand the current method.

For example, add something lke this to your fragment:
`public void updateCall(int newValue) {
        //Update data...
    }`

And this to the method in the activity:
`public void setLastCount(int newValue) {
        this.lastCount = newValue;
        ((DummyFragment) example).updateCall(newValue);
    }`

Comment: Thansk for that. I have tried it with an interface before and got to a similar point. I could _deliver_ my message to the activity, but then could not _forward_ it to the fragment, because since the fragments _live_ inside the viewpager, I cannot get a hold of them via 'findFragmentByID'. I'll try your other suggestion later. Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get your solution implemented. I don't know how to replace the `((DummyFragment) example).updateCall(newValue)` line properly with my values. I have it like this `((FragmentCalculations)).updateCall(newValue);`, but Android Studio underlines the 'FragmentCalculations' bit and says "Expression expected".

Comment: `((DummyFragment) example).updateCall(newValue)`
DummyFragment is your target Fragment class and example is the instance in your MainActivity.
(In your MainActivity use something like `private DummyFragment example;` and in your onCreate `example = new DummyFragment();` so you can make method calls from your MainActivity)

Comment: Thanks mate, I am one step closer. I now get a variable in my target fragment updated. Now the next problem is that I cannot update the textview in that fragment from the update method. I get a NPE. This is my onCreateView in the fragment: `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculation, container, false);
        countedCellsRef = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.counted_cells);`

Comment: And the updateCall method in the same fragment class: 
`public void updateCall(int newValue){
        Log.d("sporecounter","update "+newValue);
        countedCellsRef.setText(""+newValue);

    }`
logcat tells me the updated value, but the update method cannot manipulate the editText. Any chance you could help me out one more time? :)

Comment: You can try to check if the fragment is added when the `updateCall` method is called:

`if(!this.isAdded()) { return; /*The fragment is not added yet, so don't try to set the new value */ }`

(Additionally you can also check if the TextView is null at method call).
At this way the TextView should not be updated when the `updateCall` method is called before the fragment is added.
And i think you should put your initialisation stuff in the `onActivityCreated(Bundle b)` method of your fragment, so you can be sure that the fragment is attached to an activity.

Comment: I got it to work!!! Thanks a lot for your input. The `Null Pointer Exception` was because I did not declare the textview as `public` and therefore the update method could not find it. I will update my initial post with all the necessary code.